# not able to deploy bean on the glassfish server

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

I am getting following error in server log while deploying bean (.jar) file using admin console
I am using glassfish 3.1 and IDE is netbeans

```
SEVERE: UTIL6550: Error in local string manager - resource bundle is probably missing.
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.LocalStrings, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1521)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1260)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:962)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.i18n.StringManagerBase.getResourceBundle(StringManagerBase.java:127)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.i18n.StringManagerBase.getStringWithDefault(StringManagerBase.java:180)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.i18n.StringManagerBase.getStringWithDefault(StringManagerBase.java:206)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.i18n.StringManagerBase.getString(StringManagerBase.java:246)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.getPhysicalDestinationFromConfiguration(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:2054)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.updateMDBRuntimeInfo(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:1864)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:186)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:204)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:121)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:249)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:143)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:406)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: UTIL6550: Error in local string manager - resource bundle is probably missing.
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.LocalStrings, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1521)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1260)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:962)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.i18n.StringManagerBase.getResourceBundle(StringManagerBase.java:127)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.i18n.StringManagerBase.getStringWithDefault(StringManagerBase.java:180)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.i18n.StringManagerBase.getStringWithDefault(StringManagerBase.java:206)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.i18n.StringManagerBase.getString(StringManagerBase.java:246)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.getPhysicalDestinationFromConfiguration(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:2060)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.updateMDBRuntimeInfo(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:1864)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:186)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:204)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:121)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:249)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:143)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:406)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: MDB00017: [TestBean]: Exception in creating message-driven bean container: [com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: No local string defined]
SEVERE: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: No local string defined
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.getPhysicalDestinationFromConfiguration(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:2061)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.updateMDBRuntimeInfo(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:1864)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:186)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:204)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:121)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:249)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:143)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:406)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: No local string defined
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.getPhysicalDestinationFromConfiguration(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:2055)
        ... 72 more

SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:246)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:249)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be a known bug:

http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15981

However, make sure the jms destination your referencing actually exists and it cased the same.

Comment: while checking JMS in admin console i am getting following error
 
SEVERE: RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/connector-resource/jms%2FtestFactoryPool'; attrs = '{}'